# Optimize the render path (Magento 1.X)

Tags: magento-1.9, render

Using Google Speed Insight, webtestpage.org, gtmetrix.com it says me make several modifyies to optimize and speed up my site render.

They say to inline small js, defer parsing js, inline small css.

I use a different template from the default one.

Where I can find the code to do it? In which files?

Im'not able to find the code I see on a loaded page on the web in any file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="it"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="it"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="it"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="it"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Stamplast griglia di aerazione sovrapposta quadrata cm 23 x 23 in plastica colore bianco | Euroshoppingonline</title>
<meta name="description" content="Stamplast griglia di aerazione sovrapposta quadrata cm 23 x 23 in plastica colore bianco. 10 pezzi" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Stamplast griglia di aerazione sovrapposta quadrata cm 23 x 23 in plastica colore bianco. 10 pezzi" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#b91d47" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/mstile-144x144.png" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Open+Sans:400,700,600italic,300|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/var BLANK_URL="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/blank.html";var BLANK_IMG="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/spacer.gif";/*]]>*/</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/base/default/css/mntsinfotech/cookieconsent.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/jquery.fancybox.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/nivo-slider.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/sequencejs-theme.modern-slide-in.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/animate.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/reset.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/main.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/main-responsive.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/mntsinfotech/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/mntsinfotech/cookieconsent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/varien/product.js;"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/varien/configurable.js;"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/wow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/jquery.sequence-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js/jquery.scripts.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/rss/catalog/new/store_id/1/" title="Nuovi prodotti" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/rss/catalog/special/store_id/1/cid/0/" title="Prodotti speciali" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/rss/catalog/salesrule/store_id/1/cid/0/" title="Coupons/Sconti" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/stamplast-griglia-di-aerazione-sovrapposta-quadrata-cm-23-x-23-in-plastica-colore-bianco.html" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.euroshoppingonline.it/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';
Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.www.euroshoppingonline.it';
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
optionalZipCountries = ["IT"];
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39508005-17']);

_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

        //]]>
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate({"Please select an option.":"Selezionare una opzione.","This is a required field.":"Questo \u00e8 un campo obbligatorio.","Please enter a valid number in this field.":"Inserire un numero valido in questo campo.","Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.":"Utilizzare solo lettere in questo campo (a-z o A-Z).","Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Utilizzare solo lettere (a-z), numeri (0-9) o underscore(_) in questo campo, la prima lettera deve essere una lettera.","Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.":"Inserisci un numero di telefono valido. Per esempio (123) 456-7890 o 123-456-7890.","Please enter a valid date.":"Inserire una data valida.","Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.":"Inserire un indirizzo email valido. Per esempio johndoe@domain.com.","Please make sure your passwords match.":"Assicurati che le password corrispondano.","Please enter a valid URL. For example http:\/\/www.example.com or www.example.com":"Inserire un URL valido. Per esempio http:\/\/www.example.com o www.example.com","Please enter a valid social security number. For example 123-45-6789.":"Inserire un numero valido di previdenza sociale. Per esempio 123-45-6789.","Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234.":"Inserire un codice zip valdio. Per esempio 90602 o 90602-1234.","Please enter a valid zip code.":"Inserire codice zip valido.","Please use this date format: dd\/mm\/yyyy. For example 17\/03\/2006 for the 17th of March, 2006.":"Utilizzare questo formato della data: dd\/mm\/yyyy. Per esempio 17\/03\/2006 per il 17 di Marzo, 2006.","Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00.":"Inserire un importo valido di $. Per esempio $100.00.","Please select one of the above options.":"Selezionare una delle opzioni soprastanti.","Please select one of the options.":"Selezionare una delle opzioni.","Please select State\/Province.":"Selezionare Stato\/Provincia.","Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field.":"Insereire un numero maggiore di 0 in questo campo.","Please enter a valid credit card number.":"Inserire un numero di carta di credito valido.","Please wait, loading...":"Attendere prego, caricamento...","Complete":"Completo","Add Products":"Aggiungi prodotti","Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest":"Scegli di registrarti o di fare il checkout come ospite","Please specify shipping method.":"Specificare il metodo di spedizione.","Please specify payment method.":"Specificare il metodo di pagamento.","Add to Cart":"Aggiungi al carrello","In Stock":"Disponibile","Out of Stock":"Non disponibile"});
        //]]></script></head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the layout files?

For example the default theme has this declared in the: "app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml".

It could also be in the local.xml or catalog.xml files.